# ng2-chart date is displayed as unix timestamp

Tags: typescript, angular, ng2-charts

I am importing a date `Object` from my database. Unfortunately the date is displayed as an `Unix` timestamp `(-62101391858000)`. I am aware of the possibility to format my date via `pipes` like this: `{{myDate | date:medium}}` but I am using `ng2-charts` and therefore I have to solve this in another way.
My chart is displayed like this:

```
<base-chart class="chart" 
    [datasets]="lineData" 
    [labels]="lineLabels" 
    [options]="lineChartOptions" 
    [colors]="lineChartColours"
    [legend]="lineChartLegend" 
    [chartType]="lineChartType">
</base-chart>
```

I tried to find `<base-chart>` but it is hidden somewhere in the `ng2-charts` magic.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now, instead of trying to `pipe` the output in the frontend i simply did a `typecast`:

```
this.temp1.push(new Date(data[i]["truncStartTime"]).toLocaleDateString());
```

instead of:

```
this.temp1.push(data[i]["truncStartTime"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to state that the time is in UNIX time (Moments.js - tag 'X').

```
  scales: {
  xAxes: [{

              type: 'time',
              time: {
                    format: 'X',
                    displayFormats: {minute: 'HH:mm'},
                                         // round: 'day'
                                  tooltipFormat: 'll HH:mm'
                  },
```

the important part is the **'format: 'X'**